# Target a div ID that appears on a page containing a specific class - CSS or jQuery? Both?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm very new at this, so please forgive me if I'm not explaining this correctly, or not providing the right code (or providing too much).

So near the top of my page I have this code:

```
<div id="javo-detail-item-header-wrap" class="container-fluid javo-spyscroll lava-spyscroll" style="padding: 0px; z-index: 1;">
```

And then further down the page:

```
<div id="post-2355" class="single-item-tab post-2355 property type-property status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry property_type-ny property_status-sold">
```

I want to target `#javo-detail-item-header-wrap`from the first line of code, but ONLY when `.property_status-sold`is also on the page.

From what I understand it's not possible to target an element via CSS by its descendant, right? I've seen mentions online of a similar situation being solved by renaming the first ID with jQuery - is that what needs to be done here?

IS the second element even a descendant of the first if it's not in the same div?

Comment: Is `.property_status-sold` child of the `#javo-detail-item-header-wrap` ?

Comment: I'm not positive, it's below it in Chrome Inspect Element, but not nested within it, so does that mean it's not a child of it? This is the page in question - http://mytestsite-b1.info/property/1322-stratford-avenue-mixed-use-2/ It's the gray sticky bar that I'm trying to hide.

Comment: You can simply do it by using `jQuery-selectors` and testing their `length` property..

Comment: @Rayon I wrote that 15 minutes ago.

Comment: @Shomz, I commented it 13 mins ago.. And I did not see `jQuery` version of your code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your full code structure, I'd say 99% it's not possible using plain CSS. Doing it in JavaScript should be quite easy:

```
function getIt() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('property_status-sold').length > 0)
    return document.getElementById('javo-detail-item-header-wrap');
}
```

To get your element, just call the function `getIt` (and give it a better name) - it will return either the element reference, or `undefined` if either the `.property_status-sold` is not found or the actual element `#javo-detail-item-header-wrap` is missing for some reason.

---

If you really like jQuery that much, here's the above code (note that it returns a jQuery object, not the element reference - you can use `.get(0)` to the the element reference):

```
function getIt() {
  if ($('.property_status-sold').length > 0)
    return $('#javo-detail-item-header-wrap');
}
```

---

A quick-fix for hiding that element:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if (jQuery('.property_status-sold').length > 0)
    jQuery('#javo-detail-item-header-wrap').hide();
})
```

This is all you need.

Comment: It's not that I particularly like jQuery (or know it well), I just guessed with my limited knowledge it would be the best way to handle this - but maybe not? I'm sorry I don't understand though - how do a then apply my CSS to that function?

Comment: Plain JS is just much faster, but since you're already using jQuery, stay with it. Ideally, you'd define a CSS class with a set of rules you'd like to apply to the element, and then just do `var el = getIt(); if (el) el.addClass('myClassHere');`... if you just want to hide it, use `el.hide()` instead.

Comment: Note, replace the dollar-sign `$` with `jQuery` on your website.

Comment: Thank you - but I think I may have overstated my knowledge of jQuery...which is about zero. As in my knowledge is limited to that of I know where the function is supposed to go in the backend, but nothing really about crafting it.

Comment: Just copy that last snippet of code in my answer, but replace the dollar sign with `jQuery` (so it's like: `if (jQuery('.property_status...etc`), and then just do the code from my comment above, depending on what you want to do with the element.

Comment: There, wrote you an update with all the code you need.

Comment: and then where it says ('myClassHere') I can write something like ('Sold_sticky') ? And then target it with CSS like #sold_sticky {display:none;} ?

Comment: Absolutely! Just make sure you use `.sold_sticky` (dot, not the hash), and match the case (`sold` vs `Sold`).

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, but is the jQuery snippet I'd use:

function getIt() {
  if (jquery('.property_status-sold').length > 0)
    return jquery('#javo-detail-item-header-wrap');
}var el = getIt(); if (el) el.addClass('myClassHere'); 

and then target whatever I choose for myClassHere with conventional CSS?

Comment: Yes, but you need to be careful with cases, `jquery` is not the same as `jQuery`, use my code *exactly* as I gave it to you. The quickest way to get it working is to copy the last snipped (from the updated answer) and just replace `.hide()` with `.addClass('myClassHere')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var myclass = jQuery(".property_status-sold");
    if(myclass != undefined)
    {
       // Write whatever you want..
       jQuery("#javo-detail-item-header-wrap").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: so what you want to check? .property_status-sold is available or it it blank or not?

Comment: `$('.property_status-sold').length` will help!